# How to setup Caddy to get HTTPS on my server

Tags: caddy

I've been issues to get the HTTPS address for my server. Let's say I have a domain www.mydomain.com

If I run this command it just works fine. I can get the HTTPS.

> caddy -host www.domain.com

But I have some proxies that I use for django. So I have a CaddyFile. This is how the CaddyFile is set:

```
# Django
www.mydomain.com {
    root /root/my_projects/my_project
    proxy / 127.0.0.1:8000 {
        transparent
        except /static
    }
    log /var/log/caddy.log
```

So if I run this command

> caddy -host CaddyFile

, it's not giving me HTTPS. Instead this is what the output is:

```
Activating privacy features... done. 
Serving HTTP on port 2015  

http://.:2015/caddyfile
```

So how should I configure the file or what command should I use to get HTTPS on my server with the proxy and the root folder that I set in the CaddyFile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you use caddy v1.

From the [caddy docs](https://caddyserver.com/v1/docs/cli) said:

> -host
> The default hostname or IP address to listen on. Sites defined in the Caddyfile without a hostname will assume this one. This is usually used with -port to quickly get simple sites up and running without a Caddyfile.

The `-host` option maybe ignored your Caddyfile.

If your Caddyfile is in the same directory with `caddy` binary, try remove all args, just run `caddy`. It will automatically picks up the Caddyfile.

Otherwise, try this `caddy -conf <path/to/your/Caddyfile>`